# Swift/Parse - "AnyObject is not convertible to String"

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to receive a string from Parse in swift but I get an error saying:
`AnyObject is not convertible to String` Here is my code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"NewsClass")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("5tZMCa5XyX") {
    (news3: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && news3 != nil {
        println(news3)
        let description3 = news3["Description"] as! String


    } else {
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: In swift, strings and int are objects, you need to cast it to object using NSString and NSInteger. Pl. refer to the below stack over flow discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449080/swift-anyobject-is-not-convertible-to-string-int

Comment: @shri I get the same error when casting it as a NSString

Comment: Try it as a conditional cast: `if let description = news3["Description"] as? String { ...`

Comment: @DanNichols When I try that  I get an error saying `String? is not convertable to StringLiteralConvertable`

Comment: it should be if let description = news3!["Description"] as? String {